# How to changes styles on first elements using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap and have an accordion like the following

```
<accordion>
   <panel class='panel-body'>
       contents..
   </panel>
</accordion>
<accordion>
   <panel class='panel-body'>
       contents..
   </panel>
</accordion>
<accordion>
   <panel class='panel-body'>
       contents..
   </panel>
</accordion>
```

I only want to change the first panel-body background color using CSS only.

I have tried

```
.panel-body:nth-of-type(1){
    background-color: red;
}

.panel-body:first-child{
    background-color: red;
}
```

but they both changes all accordion panel's background color to red.

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're selecting all `.panel-body`s that are the first child of their parent. In this case, all of the panel bodies are the first child - they are the first child of their corresponding `accordion` parents.

You probably would want to select the `.panel-body` within the first `accordion`:

```
accordion:first-child > .panel-body
```

That looks for the first `accordion`, then selects the `.panel-body` inside it.

The `>` symbol represents "direct descendant", meaning the `.panel-body` selected must be a direct child of the first `accordion` (i.e. not more than one level deeper than the `accordion`).

Answer (score 1):

Add `accordion:nth.of-type(1)`because you must target the first accordion tag too.

```
accordion:nth-of-type(1) .panel-body:nth-of-type(1){
    background-color: blue;
}

.panel-body:first-child{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle :) http://jsfiddle.net/n29kw/

you can also write it like this

```
accordion:nth-of-type(1) .panel-body{
    background-color: blue;
}

.panel-body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
container:first-child .panel_body
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Where `container` is the element in which the list of `accordion` elements is.